# POST dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I post a dictionary into C# Web server, want to ask how to get the POST dictionary?
below are my sample dictionary

```
{"Debtor":{"CompanyName":"Big Company","AccNo":"300-G002","DocDate":"26-November-2012"}}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "json/PostSalesOrderData", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Dictionary<string, Object.Test> PostSalesOrderData(object data);

    public Dictionary<string, Object.Test> PostSalesOrderData(object data)
    { 
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string str = serializer.Serialize(data);

        Dictionary<string, Object.Test> userData = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Object.Test>>(str);

        return userData;

    }
```

Xcode Response string

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Object. The token '"' was expected but found 'D'.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

Comment: Which web server are you exactly using and which technology is your website based o? ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC or maybe even something completely different?

Comment: i'm using POST Request from Xcode to C# web server. 
using ASP.NET MVC



public Dictionary<string, Object.Test> PostSalesOrderData(object data)
        {
           


            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string str = serializer.Serialize(data);

            Dictionary<string, Object.Test> userData = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Object.Test>>(str);

            return userData;

        }

Comment: Are OperationContract and WebInvoke not WCF-specific attributes? ASP.NET MVC has the HttpPost-Attribute, I believe the other two are not necessary here, if you are not using WCF.

Comment: do you have any sample that i can deserialize my POST object ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WCF, it might be able to parse automatically if you change `PostSalesOrderData(object data)` to `PostSalesOrderData(Dictionary<string, VALUETYPE> data)`.

If that does not work, get the raw string and deserialize manually:

```
public Dictionary<string, Object.Test> PostSalesOrderData(string data)
{
    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>(data);

    ...
}
```

I did not test the deserialization to `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`, you might need to put your actual model-type there, if every entry is of the same type. You may also need to set `[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]` for this to work.

Comment: <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Object. The token '"' was expected but found 'D'.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>